# Cannot store file name in database

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a php file for uploading the images, rename it so it has a distinctive value that can be fetch for other usages, the upload part works but when I take the variable($fileNewName) and try to insert it into the database, it doesn't work.

```
session_start();
include_once('dbh-inc.php');
$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));


$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
    if ($fileError === 0) {
        if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('',true).".". $fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = '../uploads/' .$fileNameNew;

            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$fileDestination);
            $sql = "UPDATE stenden_users SET userImagePath = ".$fileNameNew." WHERE userID =" .$_SESSION['u_id'] ; 
            if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql)) {
                $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                if($result == FALSE){
                    echo "failed";
                } else {
                    echo "success!!!";
                }


            }


            echo "Your image was successfully uploaded! ";
        } else {
            echo "The size of file is too big";
        }
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading your file";
    }
} else {
    echo "You cannot upload files of this type";
}
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Your problems with query syntax will probably go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL syntax incorrect, you can change SQL query to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE stenden_users SET userImagePath = '".$fileNameNew."' WHERE userID =" .$_SESSION['u_id'] ;
```

Comment: it worked,cam on ban :),  by the way the variables I created inside the if statement ( $fileDestination, $fileNameNew), Can I be able to use those variables outside the if statement, for another sql query ?